# Python: How to convert hex to dotted decimal

Tags: python, ip, hex, decimal

Given netmask in hex format e.g.0xffffff00 (or sometimes without the '0x' in front), I would like to convert it into dotted decimal format e.g.255.255.255.0.

What I have tried so far:

```
print binascii.a2b_hex("0xffffff00")

print bytearray.fromhex("ffffff00").decode()

mystring = "0xffffff00"
print mystring.decode('hex')
```

But the error returned states "non-hexadecimal digit found". May I know what am I doing wrong that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `x` is not a hexadecimal character.

Comment: Your answer is the same as duplicate. Just use `struct.pack(">L", addr_long)` instead of `struct.pack("<L", addr_long)`. eg. big endian instead of little endian

Comment: use socket.inet.ntoa() for IPv4 addresses.